# Create and compile a base class to use in other c++ projects (ROS)

Tags: c++, cmake, ros

I would like to compile a project so I would be able to use it as a library in other projects.
To be more precise it is a base class that I would like many other project I use to inherit from.

```
├── include
│   ├── MyBase.hpp
│   ├── ...
│   └── Utils.hpp
└── src
    ├── MyBase.cpp
    ├── ...
    └── Utils.cpp
```

After I followed a tutorial and adjusted My `CMakeLists.txt`  file and now it looks like this.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_commons)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
roscpp
tf
)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS tf
               INCLUDE_DIRS include)


include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
   include/
)
###########
## Build ##
###########

add_library(my_commons SHARED
src/MyBase.cpp
src/Utils.cpp
)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against

set_target_properties(my_commons PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

target_link_libraries(my_commons
                        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                        ${roscpp_LIBRARIES}
)


install(DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)


# Install library
install(TARGETS my_commons
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

It compiles fine, but I am not sure what needs to be added in other projects' CMakeFiles and how to use it there.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the CMakeLists.txt file you included above, you need to add a libraries line in the catkin_package as follows:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include 
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS  tf
)
```

Then in other nodes, you would include the package in packages.xml:

```
<build_depend>my_commons</build_depend>
```

And in the CMakeLists.txt file you would need to find the my_commons package and link it against a library or executable you are trying to build by doing the following:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  my_commons
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS my_commons
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${my_commons_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, however, when trying to use it for example like this:
class MyManagerNodelet : public indoor_commons::MyBaseNodelet

I am getting the following error:
Failed to load nodelet [/my_manager] of type [my_manager/MyManagerNodelet] even after refreshing the cache: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class my_manager/MyManagerNodelet with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are .....